# Scala Option higher order functions instead of pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, higher-order-functions

What is the higher order function equivalent expression to the following?

```
def isRepeated:Boolean = {
  prev match {
    case Some(a) => a.prev match {
      case Some(b) => b.equals(this)
      case None => false
    }
    case None => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is equivalent:

```
def isRepeated:Boolean = prev.exists(_.prev.exists(_.equals(this)))
```

Comment: Yes. Beautiful! Got to love scala!